# Steps inbetween? Weil's zeta function

Tags: algebraic-geometry, zeta-functions, betti-numbers

[image]

[image]

Why is it that, that is "just" what the Zeta function is? What happened in between? I messed around with it for roughly an hour and couldn't get it to come out right.

The second photo is just for the exact definition of how we are taking the Zeta function.

Comment: Did you use the power series for $\log(1-X)$?

Comment: Yes, I was using this http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~mmustata/zeta_book.pdf as my reference but I dont understand when they rewrite N_m as a sum with $a$ and $r$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition, if $X = \mathbb{P}^1$, so that $N_m = q^m + 1$, then
\[
Z(X,s) = \exp\left(\sum_{m = 1}^{\infty} \frac{q^m + 1}{m} q^{-ms}\right) = \exp\left(\sum_{m = 1}^{\infty} \frac{q^m}{m} q^{-ms} + \sum_{m = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{m} q^{-ms}\right),\]
which is
\[\exp\left(\sum_{m = 1}^{\infty} \frac{q^{-m(s - 1)}}{m}\right) \exp\left(\sum_{m = 1}^{\infty} \frac{q^{-ms}}{m}\right).\]
As
\[\log \frac{1}{1 - z} = \sum_{m = 1}^{\infty} \frac{z^m}{m}\]
for $|z| < 1$, it follows by letting $z = q^{-(s - 1)}$ in the first term and $z = q^{-s}$ in the second term that
\[Z(X,s) = \exp\left(\log \frac{1}{1 - q^{-(s - 1)}}\right) \exp\left(\log \frac{1}{1 - q^{-s}}\right) = \frac{1}{(1 - q^{-(s - 1)}) (1 - q^{-s})}\]
whenever both $|q^{-(s-1)}| < 1$ and $|q^{-s}| < 1$. By analytic continuation, this identity extends to all $s \in \mathbb{C}$ for which the right-hand side is well-defined.